# What are Keycloak's OAuth2 / OpenID Connect endpoints?

Tags: keycloak

We are trying to evaluate Keycloak as an SSO solution, and it looks good in many respects, but the documentation is painfully lacking in the basics.

For a given Keycloak installation on `http://localhost:8080/` for realm `test`, what are the [OAuth2 Authorization Endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1), [OAuth2 Token Endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2) and [OpenID Connect UserInfo Endpoint](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo) ?

We are not interested in using Keycloak's own client library, we want to use standard OAuth2 / OpenID Connect client libraries, as the client applications using the keycloak server will be written in a wide range of languages (PHP, Ruby, Node, Java, C#, Angular). Therefore the examples that use the Keycloak client aren't of use for us.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

For Keycloak 1.9 and above, the above information can be retrieved via the url

```
http://keycloakhost:keycloakport/realms/{realm}/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

For example, if the realm name is *demo*:

```
http://keycloakhost:keycloakport/realms/demo/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

An example output from above url:

```json
{
    "issuer": "http://localhost:8080/realms/demo",
    "authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
    "token_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    "userinfo_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
    "end_session_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/logout",
    "jwks_uri": "http://localhost:8080/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/certs",
    "grant_types_supported": [
        "authorization_code",
        "refresh_token",
        "password"
    ],
    "response_types_supported": [
        "code"
    ],
    "subject_types_supported": [
        "public"
    ],
    "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
        "RS256"
    ],
    "response_modes_supported": [
        "query"
    ]
}
```

Found information at https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-571

Note: You might need to add your client to the *Valid Redirect URI* list

Comment: We've since then discarded using Keycloak, so I can't verify.

Comment: What URL would one use to have a login link on a web app ? U tried all of those but they don't do that

Comment: @AmirAbiri what is your alternative to KeyCloak? I'm currently evaluating it. It like the UI and would like to have all my users managed by it but I have a hard time attatching my GoLang application to it.

Comment: @Tarion There is WSO2 identity server, for one.

Comment: I struggled with Keycloak until I found this post with the magic URL!

Comment: @Can'tTell Could you please have a look at my Keycloak-related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/70376766/2886891 ? Thanks.

Comment: Note that /auth/ has been removed from the path. Otherwise this works. See suggestions from @anwar-husain below for a shortcut in the UI.

Answer (score 56):

You can also see this information by going into Admin Console -> Realm Settings -> Clicking the hyperlink on the Endpoints field.

[image]

Answer (score 44):

I'm currently experimenting with Keycloak 18.0.0, and I found that the "/auth" part is removed from the OIDC discovery URL:

```
https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

This returns a JSON data structure that contains the endpoints:

```json
{
  "issuer": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}",
  "authorization_endpoint": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
  "token_endpoint": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token",
  "introspection_endpoint": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
  "userinfo_endpoint": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
  "end_session_endpoint": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/logout",
  "frontchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
  "frontchannel_logout_supported": true,
  "jwks_uri": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/certs",
  "check_session_iframe": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html",
  "grant_types_supported": [
    "authorization_code",
    "implicit",
    "refresh_token",
    "password",
    "client_credentials",
    "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code",
    "urn:openid:params:grant-type:ciba"
  ],
  "response_types_supported": [
    "code",
    "none",
    "id_token",
    "token",
    "id_token token",
    "code id_token",
    "code token",
    "code id_token token"
  ],
  "subject_types_supported": [
    "public",
    "pairwise"
  ],
  "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "PS384",
    "ES384",
    "RS384",
    "HS256",
    "HS512",
    "ES256",
    "RS256",
    "HS384",
    "ES512",
    "PS256",
    "PS512",
    "RS512"
  ],
  "id_token_encryption_alg_values_supported": [
    "RSA-OAEP",
    "RSA-OAEP-256",
    "RSA1_5"
  ],
  "id_token_encryption_enc_values_supported": [
    "A256GCM",
    "A192GCM",
    "A128GCM",
    "A128CBC-HS256",
    "A192CBC-HS384",
    "A256CBC-HS512"
  ],
  "userinfo_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "PS384",
    "ES384",
    "RS384",
    "HS256",
    "HS512",
    "ES256",
    "RS256",
    "HS384",
    "ES512",
    "PS256",
    "PS512",
    "RS512",
    "none"
  ],
  "request_object_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "PS384",
    "ES384",
    "RS384",
    "HS256",
    "HS512",
    "ES256",
    "RS256",
    "HS384",
    "ES512",
    "PS256",
    "PS512",
    "RS512",
    "none"
  ],
  "request_object_encryption_alg_values_supported": [
    "RSA-OAEP",
    "RSA-OAEP-256",
    "RSA1_5"
  ],
  "request_object_encryption_enc_values_supported": [
    "A256GCM",
    "A192GCM",
    "A128GCM",
    "A128CBC-HS256",
    "A192CBC-HS384",
    "A256CBC-HS512"
  ],
  "response_modes_supported": [
    "query",
    "fragment",
    "form_post",
    "query.jwt",
    "fragment.jwt",
    "form_post.jwt",
    "jwt"
  ],
  "registration_endpoint": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/clients-registrations/openid-connect",
  "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "private_key_jwt",
    "client_secret_basic",
    "client_secret_post",
    "tls_client_auth",
    "client_secret_jwt"
  ],
  "token_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "PS384",
    "ES384",
    "RS384",
    "HS256",
    "HS512",
    "ES256",
    "RS256",
    "HS384",
    "ES512",
    "PS256",
    "PS512",
    "RS512"
  ],
  "introspection_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "private_key_jwt",
    "client_secret_basic",
    "client_secret_post",
    "tls_client_auth",
    "client_secret_jwt"
  ],
  "introspection_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "PS384",
    "ES384",
    "RS384",
    "HS256",
    "HS512",
    "ES256",
    "RS256",
    "HS384",
    "ES512",
    "PS256",
    "PS512",
    "RS512"
  ],
  "authorization_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "PS384",
    "ES384",
    "RS384",
    "HS256",
    "HS512",
    "ES256",
    "RS256",
    "HS384",
    "ES512",
    "PS256",
    "PS512",
    "RS512"
  ],
  "authorization_encryption_alg_values_supported": [
    "RSA-OAEP",
    "RSA-OAEP-256",
    "RSA1_5"
  ],
  "authorization_encryption_enc_values_supported": [
    "A256GCM",
    "A192GCM",
    "A128GCM",
    "A128CBC-HS256",
    "A192CBC-HS384",
    "A256CBC-HS512"
  ],
  "claims_supported": [
    "aud",
    "sub",
    "iss",
    "auth_time",
    "name",
    "given_name",
    "family_name",
    "preferred_username",
    "email",
    "acr"
  ],
  "claim_types_supported": [
    "normal"
  ],
  "claims_parameter_supported": true,
  "scopes_supported": [
    "openid",
    "phone",
    "roles",
    "microprofile-jwt",
    "email",
    "web-origins",
    "offline_access",
    "address",
    "profile"
  ],
  "request_parameter_supported": true,
  "request_uri_parameter_supported": true,
  "require_request_uri_registration": true,
  "code_challenge_methods_supported": [
    "plain",
    "S256"
  ],
  "tls_client_certificate_bound_access_tokens": true,
  "revocation_endpoint": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/revoke",
  "revocation_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "private_key_jwt",
    "client_secret_basic",
    "client_secret_post",
    "tls_client_auth",
    "client_secret_jwt"
  ],
  "revocation_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "PS384",
    "ES384",
    "RS384",
    "HS256",
    "HS512",
    "ES256",
    "RS256",
    "HS384",
    "ES512",
    "PS256",
    "PS512",
    "RS512"
  ],
  "backchannel_logout_supported": true,
  "backchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
  "device_authorization_endpoint": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/auth/device",
  "backchannel_token_delivery_modes_supported": [
    "poll",
    "ping"
  ],
  "backchannel_authentication_endpoint": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/ext/ciba/auth",
  "backchannel_authentication_request_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "PS384",
    "ES384",
    "RS384",
    "ES256",
    "RS256",
    "ES512",
    "PS256",
    "PS512",
    "RS512"
  ],
  "require_pushed_authorization_requests": false,
  "pushed_authorization_request_endpoint": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/ext/par/request",
  "mtls_endpoint_aliases": {
    "token_endpoint": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    "revocation_endpoint": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/revoke",
    "introspection_endpoint": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
    "device_authorization_endpoint": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/auth/device",
    "registration_endpoint": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/clients-registrations/openid-connect",
    "userinfo_endpoint": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
    "pushed_authorization_request_endpoint": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/ext/par/request",
    "backchannel_authentication_endpoint": "https://{keycloakhost}:{keycloakport}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/ext/ciba/auth"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can add it back with `http-relative-path`. By default is /, you can put it to /auth

Answer (score 39):

Actually link to `.well-known` is on the first tab of your realm settings - but link doesn't look like link, but as value of text box... bad ui design.
[Screenshot of Realm's General Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzkjW.png)

Comment: Shouldn't that be .well-known? (final n was missing) - I can't edit your post because the change needs to be at least 6 chars.

Comment: Agree, bad UI design. I had no idea until I read this. Note that /auth/ has been removed from the path, so many previous answers don't work.

Answer (score 23):

With version 1.9.3.Final, Keycloak has a number of OpenID endpoints available. These can be found at `/auth/realms/{realm}/.well-known/openid-configuration`. Assuming your realm is named `demo`, that endpoint will produce a JSON response similar to this.

```
{
  "issuer": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo",
  "authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
  "token_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token",
  "token_introspection_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
  "userinfo_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
  "end_session_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/logout",
  "jwks_uri": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/certs",
  "grant_types_supported": [
    "authorization_code",
    "implicit",
    "refresh_token",
    "password",
    "client_credentials"
  ],
  "response_types_supported": [
    "code",
    "none",
    "id_token",
    "token",
    "id_token token",
    "code id_token",
    "code token",
    "code id_token token"
  ],
  "subject_types_supported": [
    "public"
  ],
  "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "RS256"
  ],
  "response_modes_supported": [
    "query",
    "fragment",
    "form_post"
  ],
  "registration_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/clients-registrations/openid-connect"
}
```

As far as I have found, these endpoints implement the [Oauth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) spec.

Answer (score 16):

After much digging around we were able to scrape the info more or less (mainly from Keycloak's own JS client lib):

- **Authorization Endpoint:** `/auth/realms/{realm}/tokens/login`
- **Token Endpoint:** `/auth/realms/{realm}/tokens/access/codes`

As for *OpenID Connect UserInfo*, right now (1.1.0.Final) Keycloak doesn't implement this endpoint, so it is not fully OpenID Connect compliant. However, there is already a [patch](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-884) that adds that as of this writing should be included in 1.2.x.

**But** - Ironically Keycloak does send back an `id_token` in together with the access token. Both the `id_token` and the `access_token` are [signed JWTs](http://jwt.io/), and the keys of the token are OpenID Connect's keys, i.e:

```
"iss":  "{realm}"
"sub":  "5bf30443-0cf7-4d31-b204-efd11a432659"
"name": "Amir Abiri"
"email: "..."
```

So while Keycloak 1.1.x is not fully OpenID Connect compliant, it does "speak" in OpenID Connect language.

Answer (score 14):

**TL;DR:**

**KC below 18.0.0**: `https://${hostname}/auth/realms/${realm}/.well-known/openid-configuration`

**KC 18.0.0** and up: `https://${hostname}/realms/${realm}/.well-known/openid-configuration`

---

A more in depth explanation. According to the [openid-connect standard](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html)

> 4. **Obtaining OpenID Provider Configuration Information**
>
> Using the **Issuer location discovered** (...) the OpenID Provider's configuration information can be
> retrieved.
>
> OpenID Providers supporting Discovery **MUST make a JSON document
> available at the path formed by concatenating the string
> /.well-known/openid-configuration to the Issuer**. (..)

So according to the standard the endpoint is on `${issuer_url}/.well-known/openid-configuration`.

**For Keycloak versions before 18.0.0:**

The issuer is `https://${host}:${port}/auth/realms/${realm}/` so the openid-configuration is on:

```
https://${host}:${port}/auth/realms/${realm}/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Or via UI:

1. Go to your realm, then realm settings:

[image]

and then click on OpenID Endpoint Configuration.

**For Keycloak version 18.0.0 and onwards (auth was removed)**

The issuer is `https://${host}:${port}/realms/${realm}/` so the openid-configuration is on:

```
https://${host}:${port}/realms/${realm}/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

1. Go to your realm, then realm settings:

[image]

and then click on OpenID Endpoint Configuration.

Answer (score 7):

In version 1.9.0 json with all endpoints is at address /auth/realms/{realm}

- **Authorization Endpoint:** /auth/realms/{realm}/account
- **Token Endpoint:** /auth/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect

Answer (score 7):

**Option 1** : <Keycloak_Host>/realms//.well-known/openid-configuration

**Option 2** : Go to your realm, then realm settings

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Following link Provides JSON document describing metadata about the Keycloak

```
/auth/realms/{realm-name}/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Following information reported with Keycloak 6.0.1 for `master` realm

```
{  
   "issuer":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master",
   "authorization_endpoint":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
   "token_endpoint":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token",
   "token_introspection_endpoint":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
   "userinfo_endpoint":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
   "end_session_endpoint":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/logout",
   "jwks_uri":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs",
   "check_session_iframe":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html",
   "grant_types_supported":[  
      "authorization_code",
      "implicit",
      "refresh_token",
      "password",
      "client_credentials"
   ],
   "response_types_supported":[  
      "code",
      "none",
      "id_token",
      "token",
      "id_token token",
      "code id_token",
      "code token",
      "code id_token token"
   ],
   "subject_types_supported":[  
      "public",
      "pairwise"
   ],
   "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported":[  
      "PS384",
      "ES384",
      "RS384",
      "HS256",
      "HS512",
      "ES256",
      "RS256",
      "HS384",
      "ES512",
      "PS256",
      "PS512",
      "RS512"
   ],
   "userinfo_signing_alg_values_supported":[  
      "PS384",
      "ES384",
      "RS384",
      "HS256",
      "HS512",
      "ES256",
      "RS256",
      "HS384",
      "ES512",
      "PS256",
      "PS512",
      "RS512",
      "none"
   ],
   "request_object_signing_alg_values_supported":[  
      "PS384",
      "ES384",
      "RS384",
      "ES256",
      "RS256",
      "ES512",
      "PS256",
      "PS512",
      "RS512",
      "none"
   ],
   "response_modes_supported":[  
      "query",
      "fragment",
      "form_post"
   ],
   "registration_endpoint":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/clients-registrations/openid-connect",
   "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":[  
      "private_key_jwt",
      "client_secret_basic",
      "client_secret_post",
      "client_secret_jwt"
   ],
   "token_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported":[  
      "RS256"
   ],
   "claims_supported":[  
      "aud",
      "sub",
      "iss",
      "auth_time",
      "name",
      "given_name",
      "family_name",
      "preferred_username",
      "email"
   ],
   "claim_types_supported":[  
      "normal"
   ],
   "claims_parameter_supported":false,
   "scopes_supported":[  
      "openid",
      "address",
      "email",
      "microprofile-jwt",
      "offline_access",
      "phone",
      "profile",
      "roles",
      "web-origins"
   ],
   "request_parameter_supported":true,
   "request_uri_parameter_supported":true,
   "code_challenge_methods_supported":[  
      "plain",
      "S256"
   ],
   "tls_client_certificate_bound_access_tokens":true,
   "introspection_endpoint":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

keycloak version: 4.6.0

- TokenUrl: [domain]/auth/realms/{REALM_NAME}/protocol/openid-connect/token
- AuthUrl: [domain]/auth/realms/{REALM_NAME}/protocol/openid-connect/auth

Comment: yes, this is valid for 5.0 as well. They are documented here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/5.0/server_admin/#keycloak-server-oidc-uri-endpoints

Answer (score 3):

**For Hostname Endpoints:**

```
https://keycloak.{HOSTNAME}/realms/{REALM}/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Answer (score 2):

FQDN/auth/realms/{realm_name}/.well-known/openid-configuration

you will see everything here, plus if the identity provider is also Keycloak then feeding this URL will setup everything also true with other identity providers if they support and they already handled it