# Keycloak - Retrieve RSA public key

Tags: oauth-2.0, rsa, keycloak

I have an app deployed with docker, one of the microservices is a jboss/keycloak server. Everything works fine, but keycloak RSA public key need to be retrieved manually. Is it possible to retrieve RSA public key through REST API?

Answer (score 29):

The url `https://<keycloak-server>/auth/realms/<realm>` contains a json response with the public key.  This isn't advertised so it may change or go away.  Using `https://<keycloak-server>/auth/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/certs` and setting up something to monitor the jwks response would be a much more maintainable way of handling it.

Answer (score 8):

Since version 14 or so, this is now `https://<keycloak-server>/realms/<realm>`, i.e., no `/auth` in the path anymore.

Comment: `/auth` part disappeared between version 16 and 19. 16.1.1 has it but 19.0.1 does not.

Answer (score 3):

Just for lazy people, as mentioned by @davidav.
It means you get the regular openid-connect keys via

```
https://<keycloakserver>/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

Answer (score 2):

First, get the `jwks_uri` endpoint ([JSON Web Key Sets](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/json-web-tokens/json-web-key-sets)):

> The JSON Web Key Set (JWKS) is a set of keys containing the public
> keys used to verify any JSON Web Token (JWT) issued by the
> Authorization Server and signed using the RS256 signing algorithm.

To get that endpoint, use the [`.well-known` endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74956105/1366871), either by explicitly calling it:

```
<keycloak_host>/realms/DeepUnity/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

where `<keycloak_host>` might contain `/auth` depending on the Keycloak version (and configuration) that you have.

Or via Keycloak admin console (both in the old and new UI) `under your Realm > Realm Settings > General` then click on `OpenID Endpoint Configuration`.

Extract, and call the `jwks_uri` endpoint:

```
curl <keycloak_host>/realms/<REALM_NAME>/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

which would return you something like:

```
{
   "keys":[
      {
         "kid":"...",
         "kty":"RSA",
         "alg":"RS256",
         "use":"sig",
         "n":"....",
         "e":"...",
         "x5c":[
            "blablabla"
         ],
         "x5t":"...",
         "x5t#S256":"..."
      },
      {
         ...
      }
   ]
}
```

with a (matching) `KID` ([(Key ID) Header Parameter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-4.1.4)), one can get the certificate (`${cert}`) from the field `x5c` ([(X.509 Certificate Chain) Header Parameter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-4.1.6)), in this example "blablabla". With that certificate one can extract the public key, for instance by executing the commands:

```
cat <<EOF > cert.pem
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
${cert}
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
EOF
```

and then

```
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -pubkey -noout
```